# Generate C# entity files from my EDMX in the command line instead of from VisualStudio

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, command-line-interface

I have an .edmx file that generates C# entity files when I open it in VisualStudio and hit the "Save" operation.

How to do this from the command line? I would like to set up a CI environment that can do this before trying to compile...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the EdmGen2 command line Tool:

https://github.com/cincuranet/EdmGen2

Comment: is this compatible with EntityFramework 6.x? seems the last mentioned version in the documentation is 5

Comment: I'm wondering if this is the same tool referenced here by Microsoft?: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2008/07/14/edm-tools-options-part-4-of-4.aspx

Comment: author said on twitter that it's not EF6 compatible, hence downvoting answer, sorry

Comment: @knocte - but that is not correct, I use it with EF6 all the time in my VS Tools

Comment: it generates an empty .cs file for me